# How do I increase font size Auto Suggestions and for the log message in Eclipse (Mac OS)?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

I have been trying to increase the font for Auto Suggestion (in Java) on Eclipse (Mac OS) and the first (top) line of the log message - i.e.

> Class [Java Application] [Directory] (Date/Time)

I haven't found any working solution online, and I also can't shift to Netbeans because it crashes if I increase the font on Mac.

Would appreciate some plugins / extensions to fix it.
If not possible, then please feel free to give instructions (simple ones :p ) and do tell the locations and lines / file names' which I need to change.

Thanks for the read. :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>Looks like you are looking for `preferences --> General --> Appearance --> Color and Font.`</s>

`Java Editor Text Font for Editor text` and `Console Font` for log. You can edit and press apply.

Thing which you are looking for is based on native os. It is not in control of eclipse. You can change the Screen Resolution (Display) Magnifier preferences and can see the effect in eclipse.

Comment: I did this, but the Class [Java Application] [Directory] (Date/Time), which is above the console, that doesn't increase. And the auto suggest doesn't either. @ArdeshanaMilan

Comment: did you try by increasing size native size ?

Comment: theres no option for that in my Preferences. where can i find it?

Comment: I am saying this -->  http://www.bbc.co.uk/accessibility/guides/text_larger/computer/mac/os_x/#resolution